# Why was final not extended to apply to arrays and referenced objects?

Tags: java, final

While an array reference can be declared as final, the elements of the array cannot.

Similarly, while an object reference may be declared as a final field, the object to which it refers may still be mutable. Why so?

Comment: What would you do if you really only wanted the variable to be immutable?

Comment: An answer giving "**THE** (undoubted) reason" will be hard to find here, unless you talk to the language designers. Considering the added language complexity and possible ambiguities (like an array that is stored as a "deeply final" array in one class, and as a "not-deeply final" array in another class), I'm glad that they accepted the reduced expressiveness of the language, and avoided the "const correctness hell" that we know from C++...

Answer (score 1):

Declaring an object as `const`, rather than the pointer has a dramatic impact. In order to ensure the immutability, it is not enough that the code containing the `const` declaration must not modify fields through this reference, it is not allowed to invoke any methods on that object which could modify the object. Therefore, every method must be marked as either, potentially modifying the `this` instance or guaranteed not to modify it.

Note that the `const` attribute is still not a property of the object itself. There may be code having a non-`const` reference to the same object being allowed to modify it. Such code may pass the non-`const` reference to code accessing the object through a reference with a `const` modifier but not vice versa.

So this implies that the const object must not be assigned to another variable which lacks the `const` modifier for the referenced object. This formal restriction applies not only to fields but to all local variables, parameters, and return types.

Now think of the beginning of the nineties when there was no Generics in Java. The `Collection` classes all simply store `Object`s. In that scenario, a support for a `const` modifier would imply that such `const` objects can never be stored in any collection as there can be no guaranty that the same object is not retrieved from that collection (as plain `Object`) and assigned to a non-`const` variable.

Starting with Java 8 you can annotate any type use, including the Generic element type of a `Collection` or the `this` reference an instance method receives. This allows to implement such a `const` feature as a `@Const` type annotation using an audit tool verifying the const correctness of the code using the annotation. But since it is unlikely that all the existing Java code’s methods suddenly become marked as `const` safe or unsafe, it is unlikely that such a feature becomes added to the standard today.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `final` only impacts the actual object instead of the object's properties likely ties back to the fact that Java is pass-by-value.

The definition of a `final` variable, per the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), gives us this tidbit, emphasis mine:

> Once a `final` variable has been assigned, it **always contains the same value**. If a `final` variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.
>
> This applies also to arrays, because arrays are objects; if a final variable holds a reference to an array, then the components of the array may be changed by operations on the array, but the variable will always refer to the same array.

The *value* of an object reference is the actual location in memory to it, analogous to a pointer.  What `final` does is state that this pointer cannot* be changed through normal interactions of the program.

If you want immutable references, then use an immutable container.  An array is not immutable (as you correctly observe, its values can be changed at will).

<sup>*:  You can do a lot with reflection and [`Field#setAccessible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) if you ***really*** wanted to, but this utterly defeats the purpose.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If `final` would have been a recursive modifier (which is what I think you mean), this would have been horibble. It means that every object pointed by a `final` object would be immutable, and so on, and you can end up with the entire memory unmodifyable...

If, for some reason, you want the fields of some instances of your class to be modifyable, while others to have immutable fields, your should probably consider declaring a subclass, or hide private fields with smart setters.